# MySQL Query with Subqueries taking longer than it should

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, database-performance

I've been trying to find the cause for the slowdown in the query. The query is originally a DELETE query, but I've been using a SELECT * from

This is the query in question

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
where table1.id IN  (
#Per friends suggestion I wrapped the subquery in a subquery (yo dawg) to "cache" it, it works on other queries, but not on this time. 
SELECT id FROM (        
(
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT table1.id FROM table1 
        LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.salesperson_id 
        LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table2.user_id
        LEFT JOIN table4 ON table3.office_id = table4.id
        WHERE table1.type = "Snapshot" 
        AND table4.id = 25 OR table4.parent_id =25
        LIMIT 500
    )  AS ids )
) AS moreIds
)
```

The table in question is 16 gigs.
The server it's being ran against is beefy enough not to be a bottleneck.
Fields id,salesperson_id and type are all indexed.Checked it 5 times.

The subquery itself runs extremely fast. Subquery:

```
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT table1.id FROM table1 
        LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.salesperson_id 
        LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table2.user_id
        LEFT JOIN table4 ON table3.office_id = table4.id
        WHERE table1.type = "Snapshot" 
        AND table4.id = 25 OR table4.parent_id =25
        LIMIT 500
    )
```

In the processlist the query is stuck in the state of "SENDING DATA". But Workbench indicates that the query is still running.

Here's an EXPLAIN SELECT of the query

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'table1', 'index', NULL, 'SALES_FK_ON_SALES_STATE', '5', NULL, '36688459', 'Using where; Using index'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', '<derived3>', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '500', 'Using where'
'3', 'DERIVED', '<derived4>', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '500', ''
'4', 'DERIVED', 'table4', 'index_merge', 'PRIMARY,IDX_9F61CEFC727ACA70', 'PRIMARY,IDX_9F61CEFC727ACA70', '4,5', NULL, '67', 'Using union(PRIMARY,IDX_9F61CEFC727ACA70); Using where; Using index'
'4', 'DERIVED', 'table3', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,IDX_C077730FFFA0C224', 'IDX_C077730FFFA0C224', '5', 'hugeDb.table4.id', '381', 'Using where; Using index'
'4', 'DERIVED', 'table2', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,UNIQ_36E3BDB1A76ED395', 'UNIQ_36E3BDB1A76ED395', '5', 'hugeDb.table3.id', '1', 'Using where; Using index'
'4', 'DERIVED', 'table1', 'ref', 'SALESPERSON,SALES_FK_ON_SALES_STATE', 'SALES_FK_ON_SALES_STATE', '5', 'hugeDb.table2.id', '115', 'Using where'
```

Here are the SHOW CREATE TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE `table4` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `logo_file_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `contact_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `license_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `list_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `routing_address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billed_separately` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_9F61CEFCA7E1931C` (`logo_file_id`),
  KEY `IDX_9F61CEFC320EF6E2` (`contact_address_id`),
  KEY `IDX_9F61CEFC79D0C0E4` (`billing_address_id`),
  KEY `IDX_9F61CEFC727ACA70` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `IDX_9F61CEFC40F0487C` (`routing_address_id`),
  -- CONSTRAINT `FK_9F61CEFC320EF6E2` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_address_id`) REFERENCES `other_irrelevant_table` (`id`),
  -- CONSTRAINT `FK_9F61CEFC79D0C0E4` FOREIGN KEY (`billing_address_id`) REFERENCES `other_irrelevant_table` (`id`),
  -- CONSTRAINT `FK_9F61CEFCA7E1931C` FOREIGN KEY (`logo_file_id`) REFERENCES `other_irrelevant_table` (`id`),
  -- CONSTRAINT `FK_9F61CEFCE346079F` FOREIGN KEY (`routing_address_id`) REFERENCES `other_irrelevant_table` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_9F61CEFC727ACA70` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `table4` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=750 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `table3` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `office_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `profile_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_C077730FFFA0C224` (`office_id`),
  KEY `IDX_C077730FA76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_C077730FCCFA12B8` (`profile_id`),
  -- CONSTRAINT `FK_C077730FA76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `other_irrelevant_table` (`id`),
  -- CONSTRAINT `FK_C077730FCCFA12B8` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `other_irrelevant_table` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_C077730FFFA0C224` FOREIGN KEY (`office_id`) REFERENCES `table4` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=382425 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_36E3BDB1A76ED395` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_36E3BDB1A76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `table3` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=174049 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `salesperson_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `count_active_contracts` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `average_initial_price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `average_contract_value` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_sold` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `services_scheduled_today` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `services_scheduled_week` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `services_scheduled_month` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `services_scheduled_summer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serviced_today` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serviced_this_week` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serviced_this_month` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serviced_this_summer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `autopay_account_percentage` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
  `value_per_door` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_paid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sales_status_summary` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `total_serviced` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `services_scheduled_year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serviced_this_year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `services_scheduled_yesterday` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serviced_yesterday` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `SALESPERSON` (`type`),
  KEY `SALES_FK_ON_SALES_STATE` (`salesperson_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `SALES_FK_ON_SALES_STATE` FOREIGN KEY (`salesperson_id`) REFERENCES `table2` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=181662521 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Thanks for including the EXPLAIN. Also when asking SQL optimization questions, you should include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table referenced in the query, so we can know any indexes you have created so far, and also data types and constraints. Help us help you!

Comment: TIL. Thank you Bill. But how do I fix this? I'll include the create statements in a moment

Comment: Added the SHOW CREATE TABLES.

Comment: I edited the SHOW CREATE TABLES to arrange the tables in dependency order, otherwise we get foreign key errors. Also commented out irrelevant FK's, removed superfluous quotes and added semicolons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY" in the explain, it isn't caching the result of the subquery. It's re-executing the subquery many times (once for each distinct value in the outermost query). I see in the explain that your outermost query is examining 36 million rows. So this is probably running the subquery many, *many* times.

This is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html

> For DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, the subquery is re-evaluated only once for each set of different values of the variables from its outer context. For UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY, the subquery is re-evaluated for each row of the outer context.

One way to avoid this is to use a subquery as a **derived table** instead of as the argument to an `IN()` predicate. This is a better way to do a semi-join like you're doing.

```
SELECT ... FROM TableA 
WHERE TableA.id IN (SELECT id FROM ...)
```

Should be equivalent to:

```
SELECT ... FROM TableA 
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ...) AS TableB 
    ON TableA.id = TableB.id
```

The use of DISTINCT in the subquery means there's only one row per id returned by the subquery, so the join won't multiply the number of rows from TableA if there are multiple matches. This makes it a *semi-join*.

The following should do better:

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1 
JOIN (
    SELECT table1.id FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.salesperson_id 
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table2.user_id
    LEFT JOIN table4 ON table3.office_id = table4.id
    WHERE table1.type = 'Snapshot'
    AND table4.id = 25 OR table4.parent_id =25
    LIMIT 500
) AS ids ON table1.id = ids.id;
```

You might also try to get rid of the index_merge. You're getting that because you're using `OR` for two different indexed columns in table4. It uses both indexes, and then unions them. Sometimes† it's better to use a UNION of two subqueries explicitly, instead of relying on the index_merge.

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1 
JOIN (
    SELECT table1.id FROM table1 
    JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.salesperson_id 
    JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table2.user_id
    JOIN (
        SELECT id FROM table4 WHERE id=25
        UNION
        SELECT id FROM table4 WHERE parent_id=25
    ) AS t4 ON table3.office_id = t4.id
    WHERE table1.type = 'Snapshot'
    LIMIT 500
) AS ids ON table1.id = ids.id;
```

You're also using LEFT JOIN unnecessarily, so I replaced it with JOIN. The MySQL optimizer will silently convert it to an inner join, but I think you should study what LEFT JOIN means, and use it when it's called for.

† I say "sometimes" because which method is best might depend on your data, so you should test it both ways.

Comment: Wow, just wow. Thank you Bill! This answer is much more than I could've hoped for. I cannot express my gratitude to you! Your answer has uplifted my MySQL skills by more than a few months of work. Also, I found another solution to my problem. I'll post it in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Due to me needing to limit a delete query with joins(which isn't possible in mysql), there is an another option. Which is in no way the better one (Can't beat Bill's answer).

But it works, and the query is extremely fast, albeit, not very flexible. Because it has a minimum amount of rows it can pull, which for a 38M row table is 575k (no idea why)

But here it is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 
    JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.salesperson_id 
    JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table2.user_id
    JOIN table4 ON table3.office_id = table4.id
WHERE table1.type = "Snapshot" 
    AND table4.id = 113 OR table4.parent_id =113
    AND RAND()<=0.001;
```

But Bill's answer should be more than enough for everyone.
P.S. I'll ask the question about RAND() in a Where Clause and will post the link here. Maybe it will help some desperate dev in 2025.

Comment: FWIW, you *can* use multi-table DELETE syntax in MySQL. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: I can't limit it, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

You got carried away with nesting, etc.

```
SELECT  table1.*
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  table1.id
            FROM  table1
            JOIN  table2  ON table2.id = table1.salesperson_id
            JOIN  table3  ON table3.id = table2.user_id
            JOIN  table4  ON table3.office_id = table4.id
            WHERE  table1.type = "Snapshot"
              AND  table4.id = 25
               OR  table4.parent_id =25
            LIMIT  500 
    ) AS ids
    JOIN  table1 USING(id)
```

Some discussion:

- It is better to find the 500 ids and throw them into a tmp table than to haul around all the columns of `table1.*`.  Hence the subquery with `LIMIT 500`.
- Bill's `UNION` seems to be unnecessary since the Optimizer decided to use "index merge union".  This may be only the second time I have seen that feature in use!
- `IN ( SELECT ... )` is probably never faster than an equivalent `JOIN` or `EXISTS`, whichever is appropriate.  (`JOIN` is appropriate for your case.)
- For `table4`, you have a perfectly good 'natural PK in `logo_file_id`, why not get rid of `id` and promote that to PK?  (Similarly in `table2`.)
- Aarrgghh...  By doing my previous suggestion, you can bypass `table2`!
- `table1` has 181M rows?  `INT` is always 4 bytes.  You have a lot of columns that sound like small counters; consider using `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte; range: 0..255) or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`.  That should shrink the size of the table significantly, thereby speeding up cacheability and use of the table somewhat.